# transition property for left does not provide smooth animation

Tags: html, css

why does the transition property for left not work in my case. I cannot identify my mistake and the animation is not transitioning at all. I have used this transition in the class `.Kakashi` and `.insideleftthree`.

codepen : https://codepen.io/aronnora/pen/abOrwbE

HTML

```
<div class="main">
      <div class="left">
        <div class="insideleftone"></div>
        <div class="insidelefttwo"></div>
        <img src="Kakashi.jpg" class="Kakashi" alt="Kakashi"></img>
        <div class="insideleftthree"></div>
    </div>
      <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.insideleftthree{
  background-color: pink;
  position:relative;
  width:50%;
  height:22.5rem;
  transition: left 1s, opacity 1s;
  opacity : 0.5;
}

.insideleftthree:hover{
  left:50%;
  opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: The default (initial) value for `left` is `auto`, which you cannot transition from/to. Assign a value like `0` on the idle state for `.insideleftthree` and you should get what you're after.

Comment: that works perfect. Thank you.